# Ubuntu 20.04 with postfix + OpenDKIM, not sign my emails

Tags: postfix, dkim

I've configure Postfix + OpenDkim in Ubuntu 20.04 server, and has a problem. Postfix not sign emails, with silent work, not logs with errors.

### Postfix

#### main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = central.mydomain.com ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
compatibility_level = 2
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = central.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

#### master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
policyd-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn
    user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
```

### DKIM

#### /etc/opendkim.conf

```
Syslog                  yes
UMask                   007
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
Mode                    sv
SubDomains              no
AutoRestart         yes
AutoRestartRate     10/1M
Background          yes
DNSTimeout          5
SignatureAlgorithm  rsa-sha256
Socket    local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
PidFile               /run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
OversignHeaders         From
TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key
UserID                opendkim
KeyTable           refile:/etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table
ExternalIgnoreList  /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
InternalHosts       /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
```

Keys are on /etc/opendkim/keys/mydomain.com own all by opendkim:opendkim and chmod correct.

#### /etc/opendkim/signing.table

```
*@mydomain.com    default._domainkey.mydomain.com
```

#### /etc/opendkim/key.table

```
default._domainkey.mydomain.com     mydomain.com:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/mydomain.com/default.private
```

#### /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts

```
127.0.0.1
176.xxx.xxx.xxx
localhost
*.mydomain.com
```

#### checking

```
opendkim-testkey -d mydomain.com -s default -vvv
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'default._domainkey.mydomain.com'
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
opendkim-testkey: key OK
```

Restart two daemons but not work and not show any error on messages or mail.log.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue. For me the fix was to change `*@mydomain.com` to simply `mydomain.com` in the signing table file (**/etc/opendkim/signing.table** in your example).

Comment: This worked for me too. check also /var/log/mail.log for opendkim messages.